# Acestream/Sopcast on Ubuntu 17.04/17.10

Tags: streaming, sopcast

I was trying to use acestream/sopcast on Ubuntu 17.04/17.10 but have no luck in getting it installed.

I tried the steps mentioned on the below post which is for 16.04 LTS, however I was not successful.

As per steps mentioned at [How to watch Acestream / Sopcast Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/a/972690/586692):

```sh
#Install acestream-engine
echo 'deb http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu/ trusty main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/acestream.list
sudo wget -O - http://repo.acestream.org/keys/acestream.public.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acestream-engine

#Install Kodi (XBMC)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi kodi-pvr-iptvsimple kodi-audioencoder-* 

#Install addon p2p-streams for Kodi (video)
https://superrepo.org/get-started/

#Start acestreamengine no root
acestreamengine --client-console
or
acestreamengine --client-gtk

#Start KODI
Video - addons - p2p-streams - Addon Website-parsere
```

(Here I dont want to install KODI and want to run with the default VLC player).

From the above answer, it is asking to add the repository which is built for "trusty", but it is old Ubuntu version. What should be done for newer Ubuntu version as acestream repository is not available?

EDIT - I have already tried installing the windows version using wine ([steps are shared by kuni_zdenek below](https://askubuntu.com/a/972690/586692)). But I am looking for a more general way to install inside Ubuntu.

Comment: That question has multiple answers. Could you please link *directly* to the answer that you used and add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please [edit] your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for letting me know. I hope I have updated my question properly now.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run acestream under Kubuntu 17.04 under wine. I made the following steps:

1. install wine-development package. Stable might work as well
2. download Acestream 3.1.1. for Windows
3. install the app using wine eg. on drive C:, the installer should run smoothly
4. set up the aliases in your .bashrc:

   ```
   ace_engine="wine ~/.wine/drive_c/users/[YOUR USER]/Application\ Data/ACEStream/engine/ace_engine.exe"

   ace_player="wine ~/.wine/drive_c/users/[YOUR USER]/Application\ Data/ACEStream/player/ace_player.exe"
   ```
5. run in terminal `ace_engine` & and then `ace_player`
6. Enjoy

I experience some minor malfunction of the image in window view mainly when resizing windows, full-screen works fine. The sound is OK as well. IMO this could be a general solution how to run acestream after updating to the latest Ubuntu release when the native packages are still not available

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this method. However I am looking for a more generalised method to install in Ubuntu rather than using wine.

Comment: I tried this with Ubuntu 18.04. wine-stable does work. Don't try to skip a step like me and pass Wine the Ace Player files from a mounted Windows installation: the programs will run but the player won't connect to the engine.