# Issues using acestream engine with Ubuntu 18.04 (not with snap)

Tags: 18.04, streaming, p2p

I was trying to play acestream content on Ubuntu 18.04, however acestream has provided us with the engine upto Ubuntu 16 only.
[Here is the download link](http://wiki.acestream.org/wiki/index.php/Download)

I then unpacked the tarball and installed the dependencies and followed the instructions from [here](http://wiki.acestream.org/wiki/index.php/Install_Ubuntu). However I'm not able to get the engine to run. I want to be able to play acestream links with media player of my choice so I'm using this- [acestream-launcher](https://github.com/jonian/acestream-launcher). My issue on the same is present [here](https://github.com/jonian/acestream-launcher/issues/19).

I did my research and found an [answer which is very outdated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763364/how-to-watch-acestream-sopcast-ubuntu-16-04-lts). Another question is [not properly answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959302/acestream-sopcast-on-ubuntu-17-04-17-10).

Please don't comment on the presence of the snap package(acestreamplayer) as I'm very well aware of that, and also in the issue mentioned above am able to use the acestream snap's engine with the acestream-launcher (also linked above).

Comment: what's wrong with vlc running on the snap's engine  ?

Comment: @mikakun I use mpv

Comment: wait for acestream to release an engine for 18.04 & in the mean time don't use acestream if you have a problem with vlc.

Comment: @mikakun Already use the snap package's engine with acestream launcher and run it in mpv

Comment: so what's the issue ?

Comment: The issue is what I've explained above. I'm doing the workaround.